# Openldap Mirror Mode replication failover

Tags: replication, openldap, failover

We have currently one master ldap server and around 400 slave servers which are partially replicated through that master.All openldap versions are same and 2.4.31

What we want is actually if master ldap server is down , another fully-replicated master ldap takes its position and partially replicated slave servers would like to continue to serve ldap logins.

So far , i've set up the 2nd master ldap server which works in mirror mode with 1st master ldap.

but i couldnt let slave servers aware of 2nd master ldap.I actually added a second provider field to our slave.conf but no luck.!

here is my slave.conf

```
syncrepl rid=001 
provider = ldap://master1IPadress
tls_reqcert=never
type=refreshAndPersist
retry="5 5 300 +"
searchbase="dc=company,dc=com,=dc=tr"
schemachecking=off
filter="here is we filter main ldap tree with unique slave server number"
bindmethod=simple
binddn="cn=root,dc=company,dc=com,dc=tr"
credentials="password"
```

how could i setup 2nd master ldap for failover without using an extra load balancer ?